# Can Turn to Frog prevent 'enter the battlefield' abilities?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can my opponent cast [Turn to Frog](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turn%20to%20Frog), to prevent 'Enter the battlefield' abilities?

Comment: Typically, if you have several questions that are not dependent on each other, you should ask them in separate threads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Turn to Frog changes a creature's base power/toughness to 1/1 do any affects that change creature's power and toughness still apply?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/when-turn-to-frog-changes-a-creatures-base-power-toughness-to-1-1-do-any-affect)

Comment: The first part is a duplicate of [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23000/409) as Drunk Cynic pointed out, but probably not the second part. So to keep this from being closed as a duplicate, I'm going to edit to leave just the second non-duplicate question, which seems well worth having!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Turn to Frog can only be cast on creatures that have already entered the battlefield, so it can't prevent ETB abilities from triggering.

Comment: Turn to Frog is setting P/T, that's layer 7b. 7a is for things like Tarmagoyf (or Veteran Warleader for an example in current standard).

Comment: The answer to the other question is a little more subtle: if the creature entering has an ETB trigger, Turn to Frog can't stop it, but if a creature has a "whenever a(nother) creature enters the battlefield" ability, Turn to Frog can stop it if cast in response to casting another creature.

Comment: I went ahead and edited this down to just the non-duplicate question - sorry for making some of your answer not apply, but as you said, multiple questions should be separate, and one of them was already there. You could post another answer on [the dup](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23000/409) if you want!

Comment: The current situation here isn't good... the accepted answer has little to do with the current question.

Comment: I REALLY wonder why I get 2 downvotes on my answer. That is usually reserved for blatantly wrong answers, which mine obviously isn't, and since the OP accepted mine, it is clear he did not ask about fringe cases such as creatures triggering on other creatures entering the battlefield.

Comment: @Hackworth I didn't downvote, but I think people do tend to prefer reasonably comprehensive answers, even if the OP is okay with shorter ones. (It's also possible that the OP interpreted your answer as a broader statement than you actually meant it as - hard to be 100% sure what they were asking about.)

Comment: Also for what it's worth, downvotes do mean "not useful" not "blatantly wrong" - it's deliberate that people have some freedom to define usefulness. If you think that the only way something's sufficiently not useful is if it's blatantly wrong, that's fine, but not everyone has to apply that standard.

Comment: I downvoted because [a significantly more comprehensive answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/28660/6692) exists, which is a valid reason because the downvote button does not say "This answer would be useful if it were the only answer". I do not wish to start an argument about how brief answers can be good too, because I know a good brief answer when I see one.

Comment: @Hackworth No revisions of the Question provide clarification to which case of "enter the battlefield" abilities information is desired about. Further, having enter the battlefield effects in play is hardly a 'fringe' case. An associated fringe case would be an attempt to use Turn to Frog on Purphoros, God of the Forge, when the opponent had devotion, and they respond by some how loosing devotion.

Answer (score 11):

There are two cases of "Enter the Battlefield" abilities.

If the ability is on the creature entering the battlefield, such as [Abbot of Keral Keep](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abbot%20of%20Keral%20Keep), Turn to Frog isn't an answer. You can't target the creature until it has entered the battlefield. Once it has entered the battlefield, the Ability has already been triggered and is being added to the stack.

However, if the ability is on a creature already on the battlefield, such as [Agent of Erebos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Agent%20of%20Erebos) or [Ivy Lane Denizen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ivy%20Lane%20Denizen), Turn to Frog is a valid answer. In response to any number of effects that would cause creatures to enter the battlefield, casting Turn to Frog while they are on the stack will pre-empt the ability. Turn to Frog will resolve first, affecting the target with the Enter the battlefield effect. When other creatures enter the battlefield, the ability no longer exists.

Answer (score -3):

In magic, when it said "target creature", that means that the spell can only target a creature that already is on the battlefield.

Some spells can target a creature (or other permanents) that are in the graveyard, or exiled, or the players themselves, but it's said explicitly in the spell. (thanks RainBolt)
The conterspells target the spell itself and not the creature or whatever that the spell will summon

So all effects occuring when entering the battlefield already happened... and changing the force of the creature will not change that

Comment: "you can only target a creature that already are on the battlefield" - outside of the battlefield there are no creatures. There may be _creature spells_ but not _creatures_.

Comment: There are spells that target [permanents](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129494), [other spells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397612), [cards in the graveyard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366461), [players](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=lava+spike), and [cards in exile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106657), so this answer isn't really correct.